# ASP.Net MVC 2 Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just installed the ASP.Net MVC Preview 2 so I can have a look at some of the new features.

However when I create a new MVC 2 project it creates everything but default.aspx, is this a bug or is this handled differently in version 2 to version 1? When I run the project it just takes me to the directory listing, I assume I could just copy one from an MVC 1 project?

**Edit**

Just to update, if I add a default.aspx to the project with the following line in its page load then the application works fine

```
Response.Redirect("Home/Index");
```

It's just the initial route request that doesn't seem to go through the routing engine. This is when I'm running it from visual studio, I haven't yet tried deploying to IIS.

Comment: My app needs the default.aspx when I run the site locally in development but on the server I can safely delete the file, could it have something to do with IIS? I do not run the app locally with IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated to the latest version of ASP.Net MVC 2 and the problem went a way. So I guess either something went wrong with my install or there was a problem with that version

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Default.aspx for MVC. There is no 1 to 1 mapping of URLs to files.

Comment: What do you need it for anyway?

Comment: It was only there to anchor the default request (http://myurl.com)in ASP.NET.  They must have figured out a way to eliminate it.

Comment: This is not entirely true. In most cases your routes will map to a page/view.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to be there in ASP.NET MVC 2, you might want to check your default routes though.

Comment: I've checked the routes and they are fine, its the template project I'm trying to run with no changes

Comment: did you delete any of the default views or other files that come along with it?

Comment: no everything is untouched, I've tried creating it again. When I run the project from visual studio it just goes straight to the directory listing. MVC 1 projects seem to work fine.

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is then, I might try deleting that one if you havent made any changes and trying to create a new one.  What is the url it is trying to go to?

Answer (score 0):

Default.aspx is typically the default page out of the box in IIS and will conflict if not override your routing in MVC. If you need a "default" page use "Index.aspx."

Out of the box /Home/Index is the default page/route, of course you can change this in the Global.asax